Django: using sqlsequencereset programmatically inside a custom command
I am trying to create a custom command on Django, which will use the sqlsequencereset command for a list of app labels inside a loop, the idea is to run this command to generate and run the sequence setval query for each table of the app.
My implementation:
        for app_label in app_labels:
            output = call_command("sqlsequencereset", app_label)
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(output)

I read inside the Django Documentation that raw queries inside cursor.execute do not support transactions, so i customized the SQL string to not include BEGIN and COMMIT keywords, but it still throws the following syntax error:
 File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "
LINE 1: BEGIN;


So apparently the styling of the output text was colored, which led to the cursor not being able to process it inside the query console, I was able to get it working by using the no_color argument with the sqlsequencereset command:
    for app_label in app_labels:
        output = call_command("sqlsequencereset", app_label, no_color=True, database='default')
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(output)

